# Bootstrap popover close button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/bdkbq5sd/)

I am adding a close `x` button to bootstrap 3 popovers but I am stuck getting it to work. I have tried various answers from this forum but have not been successful.

My popup code is:

```
// Popover Menu initialize
$('.btn-row-popup-menu').popover({
    placement: 'left',
    trigger: 'click',
    html: true,
    title: function() {
        return $(this).parent().find('.btn-row-popup-menu-head').html();
    },
    content: function() {
        return $(this).parent().find('.btn-row-popup-menu-body').html();
    },

}).on('show.bs.popover', function(e) {
    if (window.activePopover) {
        $(window.activePopover).popover('hide')
    }
    window.activePopover = this;
    currentPopover = e.target;

}).on('shown.bs.popover', function(e) {
    var currentPopover = $(this);
    currentPopover.find('.close').click(function(e) {
        $(this).popover('hide');
    });

}).on('hide.bs.popover', function() {
    window.activePopover = null;
});
```

What have I missed? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your HTML too? or create a JSFiddle/Stack Snippet or something.

Comment: Hi @vivekkupadhyay, I have added fiddle. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your *jQuery* to this will help you achieve what you are seeking as:

```
 $('[data-toggle="popover"],[data-original-title]').each(function() {
   //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
   //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
   var target = $(e.target);
   if (!target.is('.popover') && !target.is('.popover *') && !target.is('.btn-row-popup-menu') || target.is('.btn-popover-close')) {
     (($(this).popover('hide').data('bs.popover') || {}).inState || {}).click = false;
   }
 });
```

Here's your updated [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/bdkbq5sd/10)

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: Hi @vivekkupadhyay , I have another queston, if you have time! ;-) Got stuck at window resize & reposition of popover. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404514/bootstrap-popover-follow-trigger-element-on-page-resize